# Animation text async scope issues

Tags: javascript

I have a function called animte -- that pushes an initial string into a asyn function,.

```
export function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

export async function typeAnimation(text, timing, callback) {
  let concatStr = "";
  for (const char of text) {
      concatStr += char;
      await sleep(timing);
      callback(concatStr);
  }  
}
```

I want to animate the text and give animate function its return value of an animating text -- but I am stuck inside my callback

```
function animate(placeholder) {
    //console.log("placeholder", placeholder);
    //let placeHolderText = "";

    //this.holdz = "xxxxxx";

    //let that = this;

    let newText = typeAnimation(placeholder, 100, function(msg){
      console.log("msg", msg);

      //placeHolderText = msg;

      //return msg;
    });

    //newText.then( (val) => console.log("asynchronous logging has val:",val) );

    /*
    console.log("newText", newText)

    newText.then(function(msg){
      return msg;
    })*/

    //return this.holdz;

    //return placeHolderText;

    return placeholder;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want a generator function instead.

Comment: you have an example of that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator  -- I've tried to adapt it -- how would I make it work with the example I'm trying to handle?